# for key, value in other: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)(pickle)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, cookies, pickle

I use this code to get cookies and save them to file

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os

import requests, pickle


user = os.getlogin()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.headless = True
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
options.add_argument(
    f'--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\{user}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')

PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__) + "\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=PATH, chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")
WebDriverWait(driver, 5000).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="side"]/header/div[2]/div/span/div[2]/div')))
cook = driver.get_cookies()

pickle.dump( cook , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

but when I want to read them give me a Error

code :

```
session = requests.session()  

with open('cookies.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    session.cookies.update(pickle.load(f))
```

Error :

```
for key, value in other:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

> **Thanks again if anyone can recommend a better way to read and write
> cookies in the file**

Comment: try loading your cookie file and looking at the data structure. I bet you get a a list or something while you need a dict

Comment: Yes, they are an array when I receive cookies

Comment: theres you answer. either pick the correct item from the array, or iterate over it and update multiple times

Comment: @Nullman
Thanks for your help, please post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cookies.pkl` file contains a list while `session.cookies.update` expects a dictionary, so either iterate over your list and update multiple times or pick the correct cookies form the list and update using that